# Distinct Numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $x_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ for ${i=1}$ to ${m}$ and for ${j=1}$ to $n$. How many different values does $$\prod_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nx_{ij}$$ cover?

Is there an $a_{ijk}\in\Bbb R$ (there is a $a_{ijk}\neq0$ for every $x_{ij}$) such that $$\prod_{k=1}^m\sum_{i,j=1}^{m,n}a_{ijk}x_{ij}$$ covers just $(mn)^c$ different numbers for some fixed $c<1$?

I am particularly interested when $n=2^{O(m)}$.

I need exact numbers or atleast tight upper and lower bound.

Comment: I do not understand your question. For a given fixed value of $m$ and $n$ the two expressions give just one natural integer and one real number. Are $n$ and $m$ also variable within some bounds?

Comment: Vary variables $x_{ij}$ over $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: So, in plain English, you are asking about the number of distinct products of $m$ factors, each not exceeding $n$?

Comment: For the first problem yes.

Comment: $1+{n+m-1\choose m}$ is an easy (and probably not too bad) upper bound to your first question.

Comment: Is it tight and comparable to lower bound?

Comment: For the second question, as stated the answer is "No" because when $m=0$ you're always going to cover the empty product $1$; and when $m=1$ the values covered are the sums of submultisets of $n$ non-zero $a_{ijk}$, for which $n+1$ different values is optimal by induction. If you allow those as special cases, $a_{ijk} = 0^{k-1}$ covers just one number (0) for $m > 1$.